# Flutter localisations : Auto generate key - value in intl_en.arb as we type code in dart file

Tags: flutter, localization

Is there a shortcut, extension that lets me add `Keys and values` into ARB files (default and other languages) as I type my code in dart file?

*For ex:* In my build method, I want to introduce/add a new `Text` widget and instead of following process of first adding the key-value in default ARB then copying into all other languages and finally coming to dart file and adding it as S.of(context).key, do it reverse and save time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use Flutter Intl extension [for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl) and [Android Studio](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) that can generate keys and values in your intl arb files. Take a look at the "Extract to ARB files" section of their documentation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dominik. For Everyone not finding Extract to ARB files option on Command . , make sure to include the double quotes as well